# Exception in setInterval callback: MongoError: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I keep getting this error in cmd while my meteor app is running. It doesn't seem to interfere with anything (nothing that I can see at least) so I can't tell its source.

```
Exception in setInterval callback: MongoError: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value
at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:449:15)
at MongoConnection.<anonymous> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)
at MongoConnection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:774:49)
at [object Object].update (packages/mongo/collection.js:589:29)
at AccountsServer.Ap._expirePasswordResetTokens (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1137:14)
at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1174:14

at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1
at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
- - - - -
at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\2.2.11_2\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at toError (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\2.2.11_2\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:115:22)
at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\2.2.11_2\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1046:67
at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\2.2.11_2\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:455:18
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Can you please post your setInterval function?

Comment: @dyouberg, it's not part of the code I wrote. It's part of Meteor's core so I don't know how exactly to trace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating meteor (`meteor update`) to version 1.4.2 got rid of this problem entirely.

Answer (score 2):

What version of meteor are you running?

I suspect you have encountered [this bug](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/7534#r74602906), which was [fixed here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/f9f94e21d10676aaa4a8a6809cb3bbc2fa60f536).

Try updating (`meteor update`) and see if this resolves your issue.

Comment: I'm actually running v 1.4.1.3. I recently updated and that's when the bug begun to crop up. But I think you're right about it being the source.

Comment: You may need to raise this as still outstanding on that github issue.